# addLegendImage user selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am constructing a shiny app. The app displays a few GPS points on a map. Each point has a `type` and each `type` displays a different icon (or image).

I want to display a legend (a reactive legend) that appears only if the user selects something from the menu `input_gr_letter` with the relevant icon (or image) and label for that selection.

Problem: I am neither able to make the legend appear only is a use selects something from `input_gr_letter` nor am I able to show only in the legend what has been selected in  `input_gr_letter`.

Below is a reproductible example & images describing the current/expected behavior:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflegend)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

points <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
lat <- c(9,10,11,10)
lon <- c(11,10,2,12)
type <- c("alpha","beta","theta","gamma")

df <- data.frame(points,lat,lon,type)

coordinates(df)<-~lat+lon
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

library(leaflegend)
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map1", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(left = 10, bottom = 10, draggable = TRUE, 
                selectInput(inputId = "input_letter", label = "Select Letter",
                            choices = c("A","B")),
                selectInput(inputId = "input_gr_letter", label = "Select Gr Letter",
                            choices = c("alpha","beta","theta","gamma"),
                            multiple = TRUE)
  ))  

# List of Icons
listofIcons <- iconList(
  alpha = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/yellow-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
  beta = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/orange-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
  theta = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/purple-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
  gamma = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Create the map
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(
      option = leafletOptions(attributionControl=FALSE)) %>%
      addTiles() 
  })
  
  data_point <- reactive({
    df[df@data$points == input$input_letter & df@data$type == input$input_gr_letter,]
  })
  
  
  # Reactive Map ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(list(input$input_letter, input$input_gr_letter), {
    
    leafletProxy("map1") %>%
      addMarkers(data = data_point(),
                 icon = ~listofIcons[type]) %>%
      addLegendImage(images = c("https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/yellow-circle-emoji.png",
                                "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/orange-circle-emoji.png",
                                "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/purple-circle-emoji.png",
                                "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png"),
                                labels = unique(df$type))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Current behavior when the app is loaded. Problem: legend is automatically shown]
[image: Expected behavior when the app is loaded and nothing is selected in input_gr_letter: No legend]
[image: Current behavior when user selects two inputs in input_gr_letter. Problem: legend showed for all possible items & legend added every time use selects a new input_gr_letter]
[image: Expected behavior when user selects two inputs in input_gr_letter]

Comment: Please include all your `library` info, otherwise we can't reproduce your code.

Comment: Hi @lz100, I added the relevant ```library``` info. Thank for noticing this mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflegend)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
points <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
lat <- c(9,10,11,10)
lon <- c(11,10,2,12)
type <- c(alpha= "alpha",beta = "beta",theta = "theta",gamma = "gamma")

df <- data.frame(points,lat,lon,type)

coordinates(df)<-~lat+lon
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("map1", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
    absolutePanel(left = 10, bottom = 10, draggable = TRUE, 
                  selectInput(inputId = "input_letter", label = "Select Letter",
                              choices = c("A","B")),
                  selectInput(inputId = "input_gr_letter", label = "Select Gr Letter",
                              choices = c("alpha","beta","theta","gamma"),
                              multiple = TRUE)
    ))  

# List of Icons
listofIcons <- iconList(
    alpha = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/yellow-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
    beta = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/orange-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
    theta = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/purple-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10),
    gamma = makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png", iconWidth = 10, iconHeight = 10)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Create the map
    output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(
            option = leafletOptions(attributionControl=FALSE)) %>%
            addTiles() 
    })
    
    data_point <- reactive({
        df[df@data$points == input$input_letter & df@data$type %in% input$input_gr_letter,]
    })
    
    
    # Reactive Map ---------------------------------
    imgs <- c(alpha = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/yellow-circle-emoji.png",
              beta =  "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/orange-circle-emoji.png",
              theta = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/purple-circle-emoji.png",
              gamma = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png")
    observeEvent(list(input$input_letter, input$input_gr_letter), {
        if(is.null(input$input_gr_letter)) return(leafletProxy("map1") %>% removeControl("legend"))
        leafletProxy("map1") %>%
            addMarkers(data = data_point(),
                       icon = ~listofIcons[type]) %>%
            removeControl("legend") %>% 
            addLegendImage(images = imgs[input$input_gr_letter],
                           labels = type[input$input_gr_letter], layerId = "legend")
    }, ignoreInit = T)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Iz100, this looks fantastic. One thing though: if I have multiple addMarkers and addPolygons, line if(is.null(input$input_gr_letter)) return(leafletProxy("map1") %>% removeControl("legend")) makes everything dependent upon input_gr_letter. To avoid this I have (unsuccessfully) tried     if (is.null(input$input_gr_letter)) return(leafletProxy("map1") %>% 
                                                removeControl("Legend")) 
    else {
      if (!is.null(input$input_gr_letter)) return(leafletProxy("map1"))
    }. Any idea here?

Comment: why are you trying to avoid `input$input_gr_letter`? The entire expression is depend on this reactive value. If you have other `addMarkers` which do not depend on `input_gr_letter`, then write them in another `observeEvent`.